# Logs not going to centralized Rsyslog server

Tags: spring-boot, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have set up my spring application to send the logs to the centralized Rsyslog server which is running on an AWS EC2 instance.
For this, I have the following:

1. Spring boot application running on my local machine.
2. Rsyslog service running on an AWS EC2 instance.

#### Centralised Rsyslog configuration

**/etc/rsyslog.conf**

```
# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# or latest version online at http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")

#### MODULES ####

# Use default timestamp format
module(load="builtin:omfile" Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")

module(load="imuxsock"    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
       SysSock.Use="off") # Turn off message reception via local log socket;
                          # local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
module(load="imjournal"             # provides access to the systemd journal
       StateFile="imjournal.state") # File to store the position in the journal

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")

#module(load="imklog") # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#module(load="immark") # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
# for parameters see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imudp.html
module(load="imudp") # needs to be done just once
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# Provides TCP syslog reception
# for parameters see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imtcp.html
module(load="imtcp") # needs to be done just once
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### sample forwarding rule ###
#action(type="omfwd"
# # An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# # down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#queue.filename="fwdRule1"       # unique name prefix for spool files
#queue.maxdiskspace="1g"         # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#queue.saveonshutdown="on"       # save messages to disk on shutdown
#queue.type="LinkedList"         # run asynchronously
#action.resumeRetryCount="-1"    # infinite retries if host is down
# # Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
# # remote_host is: name/ip, e.g. 192.168.0.1, port optional e.g. 10514
#Target="remote_host" Port="XXX" Protocol="tcp")
```

**/etc/rsyslog.d/50-remote-logs.conf**

```
# remote logs will be stored at /var/log/remotelogs directory
# each host will have specific directory based on the system %HOSTNAME%
# name of the log file is %PROGRAMNAME%.log such as sshd.log, su.log
# both %HOSTNAME% and %PROGRAMNAME% is the Rsyslog message properties
template (
    name="RemoteLogs"
    type="string"
    string="/var/log/remotelogs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
)

# gather all log messages from all facilities
# at all severity levels to the RemoteLogs template
*.* -?RemoteLogs

# stop the process once the file is written
stop
```

#### Spring Application Logger Configuration

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="150 seconds">
  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="CONSOLE" target="System.out">
    <encoder>
      <Pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %marker %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender" name="ASYNC_CONSOLE">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <neverBlock>true</neverBlock> <!-- default 256 -->
    <queueSize>1024</queueSize> <!-- default false, set to true to cause the Appender not block the application and just drop the messages -->
  </appender>

  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender" name="SYSLOG">
    <facility>USER</facility>
    <port>514</port>
    <suffixPattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %marker %logger{35} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
    <syslogHost>172.21.77.68</syslogHost>
    <!--<throwableExcluded>true</throwableExcluded>-->
  </appender>

  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender" name="ASYNC_SYSLOG">
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
    <neverBlock>true</neverBlock> <!-- default 256 -->
    <queueSize>1024</queueSize>
  </appender>

  <logger additivity="false" level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL}" name="org.springframework">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger additivity="false" level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL}" name="org.springframework">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_SYSLOG"/>
  </logger>

  <logger additivity="false" level="INFO" name="com.paytmlabs">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_SYSLOG"/>
  </logger>

  <logger additivity="false" level="INFO" name="com.paytmlabs">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>

  <property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs"/>

  <root level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL}">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_SYSLOG"/>
  </root>

  <root level="${APP_LOGGING_LEVEL}">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_CONSOLE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

According to the configuration I am expecting the logs under the `/var/log/remotelogs` folder in the Rsyslog EC2 instance. But I am not able to find any logs here. Any suggestions what could be missing here?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Spring, but your rsyslog config seems to be correct.
Some common errors are that the firewall rules don't allow that traffic or that the file permissions are insufficient - ensure that the base directory `/var/log/remotelogs` exists and that rsyslog has the necessary permissions to create files in that directory.